# How to set Visual-Studio .NET CompactFramework Windows-CE default window size

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, compact-framework, windows-ce

This C# Windows-CE tablet application needs WindowState Maximized and Size set to 800x480 to completely fill the screen
but any time the winforms design file is opened for editing, the framework resets the Size to 640x480.
The Size then has to be set manually to 800x480 each time.
Is this a framework defect or is there a hard to find configuration setting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Configuration setting I think, the size is unusual.  Tools + Options, Device Tools, Form Factors.  Pick the one you used to get your project started, Properties, untick "Show skin" and change the Screen Width and Screen Height values.  OK.  Close the form designer window and open it again.  Beware that your form won't work well on other devices.